# I can't get the return statement to work properly

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to return return a value and display it in the console.(for now)
The user ID is passed to a "function".
The function will check for this ID in a database and should return the userName.
I know that the correct data is found because the console.log returns the correct infirmation in function itself (see: THIS WORKS)
But the returned value is "undefined" when used `return childData.userName;`

Calling the function

```
console.log( f_returnUserDetails(uid)
```

The function itself

```
  function f_returnUserDetails(a){
    console.log(a)
    var key;
    var childData;
    firebase.database().ref('/dataman-blabla/').orderByChild("uid").equalTo(a).on('value', function (snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          key = childSnapshot.key;
          childData = childSnapshot.val();
          console.log(childData.userName); //THIS WORKS
          return childData.userName; //THIS DOES NOT
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: you need add return before firebase object as well and check

Comment: What do you mean before the firebase objects, where is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return promise because this function is asynchronous.

```
    function f_returnUserDetails(a){
      console.log(a)
      var key;
      var childData;
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { //return promise
        firebase.database().ref('/dataman-blabla/').orderByChild("uid").equalTo(a).on('value', function (snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            key = childSnapshot.key;
            childData = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log(childData.userName);
            resolve(childData.userName); 
          });
        });
      });
    };
   // function call should be like this   
   f_returnUserDetails(uid).then((username) => {
     console.log(username);
   });
```

Comment: This returns in the following
`Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
catch: ƒ catch()
constructor: ƒ Promise()
finally: ƒ finally()
then: ƒ then()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"
__proto__: Object
[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined`

Comment: It's a promise. It's supposed to look like that. An asynchronous function cannot sensibly return anything else (unless it allows a callback).

Comment: make sure you adding ```.then``` after function call

Comment: you will get your response in ```.then``` callback

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, this is new to me. How do I extract the value from the promise?

Comment: You might want to read this canonical question: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Seems that instead of `on('value', callback)`, you can do `once('value').then(...)`, which lets you not mess with `Promise` constructor for a bit simpler code (also, this is wasteful given that the handler will hang on and try to resolve a resolved promise each time the value event triggers subsequently, which is a memory leak; not your fault, OP has the same problem)

Comment: @Saad Mehmood,I needed some time to see how this all works. Your code was the solution and got it all working now.Thanks!

Comment: @MK01111000 i am glad that it help or atleast it give you a direction. best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think .forEach does not play nice with breaks and returns. Try changing it to a traditional for of loop and see if that works.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
>   throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method
>   is the wrong tool.

```
return firebase.database().ref('/dataman-blabla/').orderByChild("uid").equalTo(a).on('value', function (snapshot) {
      for(childSnapshot of snapshot) {
          key = childSnapshot.key;
          childData = childSnapshot.val();
          console.log(childData.userName); //THIS WORKS
          return childData.userName; //THIS DOES NOT
      });
    });
```

Comment: The console.log returns the correct value though (only the correct one)

Comment: How do you mean return? It just logs the value in the console. It doesn't pass it back. I also think you need to add return to the firebase call. See my updated answer.

Comment: Callbacks and promises are kind of an either-or situation. `on` will trigger a callback every time; the return value of a callback cannot be used. `once` will return a promise which will fulfill at the first instance of that event, and will pass the value to `then` handler, which you can then chain into a new promise by returning a value from the `then` handler.

Comment: @B.Blunt your code returns the following: `ƒ (snapshot) {
      for(childSnapshot of snapshot) {
          key = childSnapshot.key;
          childData = childSnapshot.val();
          console.log(childData.userName); //THIS WORKS
`

Answer (score 0):

Call new function and pass the response

```
function f_returnUserDetails(a){
    console.log(a)
    var key;
    var childData;
    firebase.database().ref('/dataman-blabla/').orderByChild("uid").equalTo(a).on('value', function (snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          key = childSnapshot.key;
          childData = childSnapshot.val();
          console.log(childData.userName); //THIS WORKS
          processData(childData.userName); 
      });
    });
  };


function processDate(name){
   // You have your name here.
}
```